# IE8 and $stateProvider issue

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 the $stateProvider routing is not working and getting an error

```
Error: Not implemented
<div class=ng-scope ui-view="">
```

What should we do to fix this error?

Comment: what versions of angular, routing etc?

Comment: update your question with version of Angular you are using.

Comment: I am having angular with version 1.2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't support ie8 - so neither will its providers.
Here's the source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie